# How to make a jQuery plugin with multiple selector matches process separably on each one

Tags: javascript, jquery

This simply jQuery demo below does the following when called with
 `$('.markdown-editor').convertToList();`:
- searches within an HTML element to find all links
- builds a dropdown selection element and injects into the DOM
- adds each found link to the dropdown selection element built above

When using a class as the selector `$('.markdown-editor')` I want it to find the links within each class element and inject them into the selecvtion feild only for that element.

Right now if there are multiple matching elements it will find the links from all of them and include the whole combined list in each item instead of a separate list for each one.

The demo below has 2 divs with class `.markdown-editor`.

Inside Div 1 there is links 1, 2, and 3.

In Div 2 is links 4, 5, and 6

So it creates a selection field in both Divs which both contain links 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 instead of Div one containing 1-3 and Div 2 with 4-6.

How can I modify this o make each Div selectino field contain only the links found within that Div?

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/pbkypodh

```
/* use : $(selector).convertToList() */  
(function ($) {
    $.fn.convertToList = function () {
        var that = this;

        // build selection list element and add it before our selector
        this.before(
          $('<select><option>Please select</option></select>').change(function () {
            window.location = $(this).val();
          })
        );

        // iterate each link inside our selector and add it to the 
        // selection element we built above
        this.find('a').each(function () {
            that.prev('select').append('<option value="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">' + $(this).html() + '</option>');
            // hide original link
            $(this).remove();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.markdown-editor').convertToList();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the plugin code work on multiple elements, wrap the plugin code in `each()`.

```
$.fn.convertToList = function () {
    return this.each(function() {
        // Plugin code here
    });
};
```

This can be seen on [jQuery's plugin development guide](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#using-the-each-method).<sup>Quoting from here</sup>

> Your typical jQuery object will contain references to any number of DOM elements, and that's why jQuery objects are often referred to as collections. If you want to do any manipulating with specific elements (e.g. getting a data attribute, calculating specific positions) then you need to use `.each()` to loop through the elements.